# Can a company use a method published in an academic paper to make money?

Tags: publications, patents

Academics do not usually apply for patents for the methods published in academic conferences/journals. Can a company use the ideas/code/results in these publications in a product they make money from? How binding the university or journal licensing is? And is the situation different for the publications that are open-access (eg eLife) vs paid-access (eg Nature)?

Comment: Related: [Can I use someone else's research commercially?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19390/17254)

Comment: If I publish “buy low, sell high”, why would that prevent the concept being used? Ideas of how to make money are a dime a dozen (heck, I’ll only charge a nickel). Implementing them is hard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any **idea** that is in the public domain, is in the public domain and anyone can do what they want with it. The same goes for results.

Code is a little different, and will be covered by the appropriate copywrite laws, and many pieces of code will have a software licence that has to be adheard to. But thats just the code itself, not the algorithmns implemented in the code. Which are public.

There is no difference in this regard between open-access and paid-access journals.

Comment: This assumes that the algorithm itself hasn't been patented. Some places it is possible to patent algorithms. A controversial practice. The journal licensing in the question applies to copyright law mostly, which is about copying, not about use. Patents can also be licensed, of course.

Comment: @Buffy there are some well known cases of companies using others code and having to go to court - one springs to mind where they paid the fine and then bought the company...