# Where/how can I find out if I can use this paper commercially vs for research purposes only?

Tags: publications, copyright, legal-issues, license, artificial-intelligence

I wanted to implement this paper for commercial purposes, but the licence for use is not mentioned at all.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09104.pdf
Dynamic Feature Fusion for Semantic Edge Detection

Where/how can I find out if I can use this paper commercially vs for research purposes only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. If you're asking about using the ideas or methods in the paper, see [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/148035/17254) and maybe also [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19390/17254).

In case you're asking about using *the actual paper* itself (i.e. text, figures etc.), the first step would be to check the abstract page for the preprint rather than the pdf. In this case, it would be https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09104 The license mentioned there grants some rights to arXiv, but does not provide third parties such as yourself any particular rights. Next, by googling the title I find that the paper is [published](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/110) in a conference which [reserves all rights](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/), so any commercial use of the copyrighted work would have to be with permission in writing from the publisher. Finally, I also found [the GitHub](https://github.com/Lavender105/DFF) for the code used in the paper. The code is licensed under a MIT license, which allows commercial use.